# Java class to enforce an implementation of super classes' public methods

Tags: java, inheritance

I have the following :

```
public Class A {

    public void methodA() {
        ....
    }

    public void methodB() {
        ....
    }

}
```

I don't have control over Class A. I would like to create subclasses of Class A with a restriction that it must override methodA() (super.methodA() call must run the implementation of Class A). is it possible? is so, how?

Comment: You create the subclass, so you get to decide what to override or not to override. What are you trying to achieve? Are you really talking about sub-subclasses, perhaps?

Comment: I think so. A subclass of Class A which imposes such restrictions for sub-sub classes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First thing to understand here is that this part of requirements: `super.methodA()` means this applies to the code of the classes extending `A`, in a way defined in [JLS 15.12.4.4-2. Method Invocation Using `super`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#d5e23769)

> An overridden instance method of a superclass may be accessed by using the keyword `super` to access the members of the immediate superclass, bypassing any overriding declaration in the class that contains the method invocation...

Let's say, we want a way to create some specific subclasses of A such that whenever `super.methodA()` is invoked in these, we are guaranteed that instead of code that was in class `A` (out of our control) it will run some other code, defined in some subclass of `A` (under our control).

---

Let's see what "tools" are at our disposal to achieve above.

1. Need to create *some, specific* subclasses of `A` brings to mind traditional way to specialize - subclassing, that is we'll consider subclass of `A` (let's call it `B`) that would redefine (override) `methodA` in the way we want.
2. Need to force a subclass to provide a code that would run where we want it in superclass can be satisfied by defining an abstract method, let's call it `forcedImplementationInSubclass()`

---

Now we've got all what we need.

- We will define a class `B` extending `A`, so that all subclasses of `B` will also be subclasses of `A`.
- In `B`, we will override `methodA`, so that its implementation in class `A` won't be available to subclasses of `B` anymore.
- In overridden method in `B` we will invoke abstract method `forcedImplementationInSubclass()` which will guarantee that subclasses of `B` will have to define the code that will eventually run in `methodA`.

As a result, any subclass of `B` won't be able to invoke `methodA` implementation provided in class `A` and instead, will be guaranteed to run code defined in some subclass of `B`.

Extending `B` is the way to create specific subclasses of `A` that behave as we want. The code could look about as follows:

```
public abstract class B extends A {
    // override, so that subclasses of B won't be able to get to super.methodA
    @Override public void methodA() {
        // invoke abstract method here (subclass would have to implement it)
        forcedImplementationInSubclass();
    }

    // define abstract method so that subclass would have to implement it
    protected abstract void forcedImplementationInSubclass();
}

// extending B is the way to get what we need
public class C extends B {
    // enforced implementation of the abstract method
    @Override protected void forcedImplementationInSubclass() {
        // that will be invoked when B.methodA() is called, and since B is-a A...
        System.out.print("Hello from implemented methodA");
    }

    public void testSuperMethodA() {
        // that will invoke B.methodA() which won't go to class A
        super.methodA();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = new C();
        a.methodA(); // goes to B.methodA(), which in turn invokes C.forcedImplementationInSubclass()
        C c = new C();
        c.testSuperMethodA(); // won't go to class A
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice explanation. Does this example represent any design pattern or design principle? Looking for an opportunity to enrich my technical vocabulary.

Comment: @akash one that comes to mind is template method pattern, although I am not sure if this would be exact fit

Answer (score 4):

Once an method has been given an implementation, there is no way of making it abstract again. So, no, without changing `A` there is no way of writing a class `B extends A` so that all subclasses of `B` must provide another implementation, at least not via the type system.

The best you can do is write a method in `B` that throws an Exception at run time. This forces any subclass to override the method to be useful, but it will still compile without doing that.

Comment: If I throw an exception at runtime in Class B. How can I call the super method in the subclasses of Class B? I would like the super call to run the logic in Class A.

Comment: super will only call the implementation of the direct superclass (if that has no method, the compiler will implicetely create one with a single super statement). So indirectly the implementation of A will be called, **if** and only if the method in the subclass does use a super statement.

Comment: @500865 Can your class B implement methods as `final` and inside them call `super()`?

Answer (score -1):

I think you are talking about 'abstract class'. If you want that the subclass of Class A must override the methodA() of Class A, then you have to declare the methodA() as abstract method and Class A is an abstract class.

If any class method having some implementation then it will act as a default implementation of the subclasses. Subclasses can optionally override that with their own implementation. If you want to give implementation to the subclass only and force the subclasses to follow a contract (method signature) then this is a clear situation of abstract class.

```
class A
{
    void abstract methodA(); // No implementation.
}

class B extends A
{
    void methodA()
    {
        // Subclass implementation.
    }
}
```

Comment: OP stated that he/she has no control over class A, so she/she cannot make its methods abstract.

Comment: If methodA() has implementation in base class then it is normal to call that implementation for the derive classes. There is no other solution in normal object oriented process.

Comment: You should state in your question that "there is no other solution in normal object oriented process", as you stated in your comment.

Answer (score -1):

Before using reflection API think about the cost of it.

It is simply easy to do. For instance:

`C` subclass of `B` and `B` subclass of `A`. All three have a method `methodName()` for example.

```
public abstract class A {

    public void methodName() {
        System.out.println("Class A");
    }

}

public class B extends A {

    public void methodName() {
        super.methodName();
        System.out.println("Class B");
    }

    // Will call the super methodName
    public void hackSuper() {
        super.methodName();
    }

}

public class C extends B {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = new C();
        a.methodName();
    }

    @Override
    public void methodName() {
        /*super.methodName();*/
        hackSuper();
        System.out.println("Class C");
    }

}
```

Run class C Output will be:

```
Class A 
Class C
```

Instead of output:

```
Class A 
Class B 
Class C
```

Comment: What does this answer add that is not in the [accepted answer](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/206847/22815) from a year and a half ago?